# Project as libary. (android app)

Tags: android

I created my Android project and I compiled it to .apk.

It is project that I done.

I want create new project using the first (with class and views).

Need change only first launch Activity.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse the same apk for 2 apps but you can reuse the code. You have several options here.

1. Extract out the common parts into a library project and then have separate application projects for each app. They both would then include the library project to access the common code/resources
2. Use the new build system with gradle to define [Product Flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors) of your app. You can use different AndroidManifest.xml files from different flavors allowing you to set a different activity as your main activity. Make sure you read all about the new build system which will help you customize builds.